# magento 2.4 Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper $mapper ]

Tags: database, elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

I am getting below error

**Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [  Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper $mapper ] of Amasty\Shopby\Model\Search\Adapter\Mysql\AggregationAdapter class**

**Code as below**

```
namespace Amasty\Shopby\Model\Search\Adapter\Mysql;

use Amasty\Shopby\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\GroupDataProviderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Search\RequestInterface;

class AggregationAdapter
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper
     */
    private $mapper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\TemporaryStorageFactory
     */
    private $temporaryStorageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Builder\Container
     */
    private $aggregationContainer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\DataProviderContainer
     */
    private $dataProviderContainer; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper $mapper,
        \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\TemporaryStorageFactory $temporaryStorageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Builder\Container $aggregationContainer,
        \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\DataProviderContainer $dataProviderContainer
    ) {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
        $this->temporaryStorageFactory = $temporaryStorageFactory;
        $this->aggregationContainer = $aggregationContainer;
        $this->dataProviderContainer = $dataProviderContainer;
    }
```

I know this error is due to msql is removed as default search engine, but i need way to fix above issue please help me with it

Comment: seems you are using third party module - see this change log - https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation-for-magento-2.html#changelog use their latest version.

Comment: did you get any update @user1799722

Comment: any fix on this?

Comment: We are getting the exact same error when running compile command. we are using Amasty layered navigation's latest version (2.17.1) still we are getting issue. Can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Constructor **Arguments** like

```
\Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper $mapper
\Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Builder\Container
\Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\DataProviderContainer
```

All these **locations** provided are wrong that's why when constructing the class it gets **zero** arguments.